# WebLogic Deployment Transaction marked rollback

Tags: deployment, transactions, weblogic

We often get a "Transaction marked rollback" error when deploying to WebLogic. A restart of WebLogic helps but this error keeps on returning after a few deployments. Any idea?

Here's the stacktrace:
weblogic.Deployer$DeployerException: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Task 2 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application ABC
Target state: deploy failed on Server XYZ
weblogic.ejb.container.InternalException: Transaction marked rollback or not expected transaction status: 4

```
at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:72)
at weblogic.Deployer.mainWithExceptions(Deployer.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy.invokeMain(WLDeploy.java:419)
at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy.execute(WLDeploy.java:349)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```